# rsync transfer chunk size

Tags: linux, rsync, scp

I‘m transferring 1.1 Mb files over very poor GSM EDGE connection. My rsync command is:

```
rsync --partial --remove-source-files --timeout=120 --append --progress --rsh=ssh -z LOCAL_FILE root@SERVER:REMOTE_PATH
```

File on remote server “grows” in size in steps of 262144 bytes. That is a lot, because system needs to transfer at least 262144 (before compression) every time connection is established. When I use `scp –C` chunk size is about 32Kb. Is there a way to change chunk size for rsync?

I've tried `--block-size` but no visible difference.

Answer (score 1):

--block-size is used for the checksum, not the transfer. However, if you use --inplace you might be able to force a smaller update size, but there are a few caveats with --inplace (see the manual)

Comment: Manual says that `-append` implies `--inplace`

Comment: You're right, I missed that.